# No controllers folder in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I have downloaded a project from some website. When i run `php artisan server` it runs successfully shows server has started on 127.0.0.1:8000. When hit localhost:8000 in browser it gives http 500 error. So i checked the storage/logs/laravel.log file its blank, the logs are not going there. I don't know why. Apart from this there is not http folder inside app folder which contains controllers. So I go through the routes/web.php to see which controllers are being used so i found 'RegisterController', 'LoginController' written in routes file. So i searched for these controllers in whole project I found 'RegisterController.stub' inside 'vendor/hesto/multi-auth/src/stubs/Controllers'. I don't know how to run this project. I have attached the screenshot of app directory.[image: Following is the screenshot of app directory of project]

Comment: To be honnest I doubt someone will answer you since there is not much to say with the information you have provided. Yes, there should be a `Http/Controllers` directory and no, there isn't in your screenshot. If it is possible, can you give us the website where you "downloaded" the project?

Comment: If you deleted by mistake.. try git stash in terminal of project directory

Comment: @toyi I didn't delete the http/controllers directory. It was as it is from the beginning.

Comment: @toyi controllers are in ''vendor/hesto/multi-auth/src/stubs/Controllers' directory but they are not .php files they are .stub files. Like 'RegisterController.stub', 'LoginController.stub'